# How to use CSS Flexbox to flex boxes of multiple heights/sizes

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to use CSS flexbox to design a grid with an image in one div that will take up the full length of the parent div and then have four divs that are in a 2x2 grid next to the div like the following:
[image: Image of goal result div setup]

I'm currently trying to build this out but keep running into issues handling creating the 2x2 grid next to div 1 because I can't get the grid to wrap to always appear as 2x2 nor get each of the divs within it to dynamically split the remaining of the page width based on the size of div 1.

[image]

The code I'm currently working is as follows:

```css
#intro-section {
    padding-top: 16px;
    padding-left: 32px;
    display: inline;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
}

.flex-container > div {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 75px;
  font-size: 30px;
}

#img-box {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
   background-color: #f1f1f1;
  margin: 32px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 75px;
  font-size: 30px;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div id="intro-section">
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div id="img-box">1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I reconstruct this grid to allow me to build something close to the first image I made?

Comment: Why aren't you using a grid instead of flex, if its a grid you want? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid

Comment: Agreed. You need CSS Grid. See this presentation: [CSS Grid Changes Everything](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7kVeCqQCxlk)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something along these lines?

**NOTE:** The solution is based only on Flexbox.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#intro-section {
  display: flex;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.flex-container > div {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: calc(50% - 20px);
  margin: 10px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 75px;
  font-size: 30px;
}

#img-box {
 height: 200px;
 width: 200px;
 background-color: #f1f1f1;
 margin: 16px;
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 75px;
 font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="intro-section"> 
    <div id="img-box">1</div>
    <div class="flex-container">
      <div>2</div>
      <div>3</div>  
      <div>4</div>
      <div>5</div> 
  </div> 
</div>
```